# Settings for hosting an application in cumulocity

Tags: cumulocity

i want to configure the application to be hosted at cumulocity via uploaded archives.

The [documentation](http://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference/applications/) shows two application types, `HOSTED` and `EXTERNAL`.

If i set the type to `HOSTED`, it requires the params `resourcesUrl`, which references a repository.

What steps are required to create an application with plugins,
which is hosted at cumulocity and not from a repository?

`cumulocity.json`

```
{
    "availability": "PRIVATE",
    "contextPath": "appContextPath",
    "key": "appKey",
    "name": "appName",
    "type": "HOSTED",
    "resourcesUrl": "appResourceUrl",
    "imports": [
        "core/c8yBranding",
        "core/deviceList",
        "appKey/plugin",
        "devicemanagement/deviceRegistration",
        "devicemanagement/measurements",
        "devicemanagement/groupsHierarchy",
        "devicemanagement/location",
        "devicemanagement/deviceGroupList",
        "devicemanagement/deviceListMap",
        "devicemanagement/logViewer"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `HOSTED` applications uploaded as ZIP files the valid `resourcesURL` would be `"/"`.